# Test for emit in jasmine test cases

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, tdd, karma-jasmine

I'm learning to write test cases with jasmine for an angular app I have a following function

```
public renderPage() {
   
    this.setupData();
    //===
    this.emitEvent('onPageReady', { canSwipe: this.canSwipe }, true);
  }
```

I wanted to check if the emitevent has fired from this function ,I tried the following in test case

```
 it('should emit from RenderPage', () => {
    spyOn(component, 'renderPage');
    expect(component.renderPage.emit).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

but this gives me error ,what should be the proper approach to do this please guide

Answer (score 0):

You are spying on the method you are trying to test. Which will stub the method and not execute anything if this method is executed. Furthermore you are missing to actually call your test method or whatever will trigger that method.

What you would need to do is spy on the emitEvent function and execute your method.

```
const spy = spyOn(component, 'emitEvent')
component.renderPage();
expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled()
```

Note this is rather pseudo code to give you the general idea. This might not work out of the box

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your component in a test component

```
@Component({
    template: `<app-your-comp> (onPageReady)="onPageReady($event)"></app-your-comp>`
})
class TestComponent {
    e: any;
    onPageReady(e) {
        this.e = e;
    }
}

describe('YourComponent', () => {
    let testComponent: TestComponent;
    let component: YourComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestComponent>;

    beforeEach(async () => {
        await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        }).compileComponents();
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
        testComponent = fixture.componentInstance;
        const e = fixture.debugElement.query(By.directive(YourComponent));
        component = e.componentInstance as YourComponent;
    });

    it('should call onPageReady', async () => {
       // do something
       expect(testComponent.e).toEqual(/* some evt arg */);
    });
```